# NameError: name '___' is not defined

Tags: python, variables, input, terminal

When running the following code in terminal:

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib
import time

user = input("Please Enter Your Username: ")
password = input("Please Enter Your Password: ")
ip = input("Please Enter RPi IP Address: ")

bot = telnetlib.Telnet(ip)
bot.read_until("login: ")
bot.write(user + "\n")
bot.read_until("password: ")
bot.write(password + "\n")
```

I get an error message saying:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "con.py", line 6, in <module>
     use = input("Please Enter Your Username: ")
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 NameError: name 'pi' is not defined
```

P.S `pi` is what was fed to the variable `user`. It runs in python shell(until it gets to the telnet part but then it would obviously doesn't work in the shell). why wouldn't it run in the terminal?

Thanks

Comment: `input` should be `raw_input`.

Comment: @blender not for python 3 and above?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're executing the script with Python 3. How are you running it?

Comment: @crossboy007: this is Python 2; Python 3 would *not* throw that exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2, use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` to take string input from a user.

`input()` tries to evaluate the input as a Python expression instead; a bare string is seen as a variable name in a Python expression, hence the `NameError`. You could enter `"pi"` instead, but that is not a great user-interface.

Demo:

```
>>> input("Please Enter Your Username: ")
Please Enter Your Username: pi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pi' is not defined
>>> raw_input("Please Enter Your Username: ")
Please Enter Your Username: pi
'pi'
```